# Android, Native OpenGL/OpenMAX, Screen capture

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, android-source, openmax

### Use-case

Mirror Android Screen to PC using USB

### Potential (Native) Implementation Approaches

1. Using Android Open-Source, modify [screenrecord](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/idea133/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp) for your needs and re-install on your Android device using ADB
2. Use well known native API such as [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)/[OpenMAX](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/openmaxal/) to capture screen

### Discussion

**Approach #1** will certainly work ( under the shell account ), **however**, each time the Android OS is updated, the custom code will need to get updated to keep up with OS changes, with **approach #2** the API stay fixed and there is no need to worry about OS changes, the question is whether it is possible to implement Mirroring solely using OpenGL/OpenMAX ?

### Questions

Having the above said, what would be the best approach to mirror the android screen via USB ?

Answer (score 5):

The `screenrecord` that ships with Android 5.0 "Lollipop" can send raw H.264 over ADB.  The command line looks like:

```
adb shell screenrecord --output-format=h264 - | <player>
```

A few details are on the [bigflake page](http://bigflake.com/screenrecord/).  I've used it to mirror the screen onto a Linux workstation, but unfortunately I didn't save the VLC/mplayer command lines.  Some player suggestions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472962/use-adb-screenrecord-command-to-mirror-android-screen-to-pc-via-usb/).

You can try to do uncompressed frames (`--output-format=raw-frames`), but at decent frame rates that easily overwhelms the ADB connection, even if the screen is tiny.

Source code is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/lollipop-release/cmds/screenrecord/).

Comment: I have the screenrecord thing working, the gotcha with this approach is that in order to go around the 3min duration limitation you need to pathch the code and re-compile, and this, impose a maintanance cost each time the os is updated, a solution using conventional apis would be optimal/what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [fadden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294248/fadden), I have ended up patching through [sreeenrecord](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/idea133/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp) disabling the time limitation and adding some code of my own ( enabling ADB over USB routing ), it works, BUT, req maintanance each time the OS is updated, I wish there would have been a way for using the Android Java framework as an ADB Shell Tool as this would considerably reduce the amount of un-documented buttons I am pressing...

Comment: Could you post a code example of getting this running? I am having a devil of a time combining the sparse knowledge of this to make mine work.