# How do I display my Android device's screen on my mac?

Tags: android, macos

I would like to display my Android device's screen on my mac for a presentation. I don't care if I have to use a USB cable or wifi. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: check this thread http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34933/android-remote-screen-display-control

Comment: FWIW, the `screenrecord` in Android 5.0 will send raw H.264 over an ADB connection.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394916/android-native-opengl-openmax-screen-capture/27475298#27475298

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Starting from Android Studio 2022.2.1 Device mirroring is under "Tools" menu in "Preferences" or "Settings" (For mac users).
[How to show the screen of a physical device inside Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75888209/how-to-show-the-screen-of-a-physical-device-inside-android-studio)

## Old Answer

[Droid@Screen](https://github.com/ribomation/DroidAtScreen1) might work for you.  I've never used it on a Mac but it's just a jar so it should work.