# How to show the screen of a physical device inside Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, adb

When using an emulator on **Android Studio** I can have the screen preview inside the **Android Studio** itself, I want to have a smiliar behaviour when using a physical device instead of an emulator.

Comment: Try using Vysor App: https://www.vysor.io/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Starting from Android Studio 2022.2.1 Device mirroring is under "Tools" menu in "Preferences" or "Settings" (For mac users).

1. Open Android Studio on your computer.
2. Go to the "Preferences" or "Settings".
3. In the "Preferences" or "Settings" window, expand the "Tools" menu on the left-hand side.
4. Open the "Device mirroring" sub menu.
5. Mark as checked the option "Enable mirroring of physical Android devices".
6. Click the "Apply" button to save the changes.

Answer (score 7):

1. Open Android Studio on your computer.
2. Go to the "Preferences".
3. In the "Preferences" window, click on the "Experimental" menu on the
   left-hand side. Scroll down to the bottom of the Experimental menu
   and find the "Device mirroring" option.
4. Enable the Device mirroring option by checking the checkbox next to
   it.
5. Click the "Apply" button to save the changes.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Please follow below steps:

1. Open Android Studio, go to `Preferences`.
2. Click on the `Experimental` menu.
3. Enable `Device mirroring` at the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

It is now in Tools Windows

Settings -> Tools -> Device Mirroring