# Android Studio can't "Device Mirroring" and also can't see the "Running Devices" bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My Android Studio version:

`Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1`

`Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111, built on February 2, 2022`

`Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64`

`VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation`

`Windows 10 10.0`

`GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation`

`Memory: 1280M`

`Cores: 12`

`Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true`

`Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.21-release-334-AS7442.40), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (211.7142.37)`

My physical device (pixel 7) can work ,but it can't Mirror to the computer.

I find the resourse in [How to show the screen of a physical device inside Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75888209/how-to-show-the-screen-of-a-physical-device-inside-android-studio) said "Starting from Android Studio 2022.2.1 "Device mirroring" is under "Tools" menu in "Preferences" or "Settings" ", but I can't find it.

Comment: You have already answered your own question: Your Android Studio version is 2021.1.1 and device mirroring requires at least 2022.2.1 - do you see the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: At first I thought It has the easier way don't need to update Android studio version and still can solve the problem, but after I do it, I just realized update is more simple than I thought.Thank you.